# Any way to disable IDEA auto save Test Results?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I print a lot in the console, then the IDEA IDE will freeze for a long time saving the test results to disk. Any way to disable such default behavior?
[IDEA keep saving test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHwb2.png)

Comment: Do you have a high number for the setting: Editor -> General -> Console -> Console commands history size?

Comment: @MystyxMac The console commands history size is 300.

Comment: @MystyxMac should I set the console commands history size to 0 so as to disable saving test results to disk? But it doesn't work.

Comment: No, that's not the problem then. What tests are you talking about? And why are you writing so much to the console? Are you using some plugin for tests?

Comment: @MystyxMac I'm just printing the progress of a long iterative computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to add "-Didea.save.test.history=false" to IDEA vmoptions.
Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148840

Comment: tried. and the result is just the same as the issue. problem not solved.

Comment: @HaixiaoHu did you solve the problem in the end? seems like there is nothing useful in the linked idea issue.